# Refused to display 'URL' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: security, login, access

- Within the 'My Domain' settings  - Authentication Configuration's  I have added (as an example) https://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/ to the Right Frame URL.
  [image]
- When I go to our sandbox login page, on the Right Frame, I receive the message "www.salesforce.com refused to connect.".
  [image]
- On further investigation, the dev Console has this error:
  "Refused to display 'https://www.salesforce.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."
- I have added https://www.salesforce.com/ as a CSP trusted site.

**Question**: I have tried to update the remote settings, and Clickjack settings to resolve this issue - are there any other settings I should update?

**Note**: I have used the website: https://www.salesforce.com/dreamforce/ in this example but the same issue occurs with other websites I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that you can configure or override in Salesforce.

The issue is the originating server is sending a header ('X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin') which prevents you from embedding that page in an iFrame unless it's on the same server.

See [Mozilla - X-Frame-Options - HTTP - MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) for more info.

If you want to add a custom URL to the side bar, see [Salesforce - Customize Your My Domain Login Page with Your Brand](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_login_branding.htm&type=5) and [MyDomain Sample](https://github.com/salesforceidentity/MyDomain-Sample).